# SQL Server Keep getting error message for trigger

Tags: sql-server

I just started with SQL a few days ago and have been trying to set up triggers to automatically populate some columns such as the ones below when data is entered for employeeTimes(clockIn, clockOut, timeIntimeOut) (similarly for those not listed here). Sorry if the column/row names are confusing - pls let me know I'll change it.
Below is my trigger, and below that is the error.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dailyHoursWorked
ON employeeTimes
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @time INT
DECLARE @employeeID INT
DECLARE @error VARCHAR(30)
SET @time = (SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,clockIn,clockOut) FROM employeeTimes)
SET @employeeID = (SELECT employeeID FROM inserted)
SET @error = ('Please enter an employeeID')
BEGIN
UPDATE employeeTimes
SET timeIntimeOut=@time
Where employeeID=@employeeID
END
```

The error I get is as follows:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers in Sql server are fired based on statements, not rows.
This means that the `inserted` (and `deleted`) might contain multiple rows.

By writing `SET @employeeID = (SELECT employeeID FROM inserted)` you are assuming that the `inserted` table have only one row in it, but when updating or inserting multiple rows in a single statement that is not the case.

Also, You are assuming the same thing about the `employeeTimes` table -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,clockIn,clockOut) FROM employeeTimes
```

Will return a result set and not a single value if your table have more then one row.

Seems to me like the best way to go here is either use computed columns or compute whatever data you need when selecting the data from the table, rather then using a trigger for it.

If you really want to use a trigger for this, you can use an update statement with a join to the inserted table like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET timeIntimeOut = DATEDIFF(hh, i.clockIn, i.clockOut)
FROM employeeTimes As t
INNER JOIN inserted as i ON t.employeeID = i.employeeID
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I will look into it.  That is way easier :-).

Comment: not to be a butt..but its not the "easier" way, its the correct way.  triggers are set-based.   if you (the OP) have not heard the term "set base", I would spend 2 hours a day for a week just googling and reading about "sql server set based" search results.